# Best manner of dispatching Python's argparse subcommands

Tags: python, argparse

I am playing around with Python's `argparse` module in order to get a rather complicated and large sub-commands structure. So far, the arguments parse goes pretty well and everything works fine but I am looking for a better way to manage how sub-commands are executed.

Here is an example of my dummy/playaround application:

```
def a_func(cmd_args):
    print(cmd_args)


def b_func(cmd_args):
    print(cmd_args)


CMD_DISPATCHER = {
    'a': a_func,
    'b': b_func
}


def parse_commands():
    # Create top-level parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subcmd_name')

    # Create parser for the "a" sub-command
    parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a')
    parser_a.add_argument('-bar', type=int)

    # Create parser for the "b" sub-command
    parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b')
    parser_b.add_argument('-foo', type=int)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    CMD_DISPATCHER[args.subcmd_name](args)


def main():
    parse_commands()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, here I use a simple `dict` (`CMD_DISPATCHER`) as a map relating the sub-command name to its function.

As I said, this is just a simple example of what I want to achieve but the real project will have many nested sub-commands so I would like a better way to manage those several sub-commands.

**Do you know a better/more-professional way to do this?**

Comment: in [ruamel.std.argparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.std.argparse) I use decorators to register methods of a `Cmd` class into subparsers. Additional decorators on those methods are used for options. There is also a special method that defines "global" options (applying to all subparsers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, after some more research I have found a good way that fits my needs: `set_defaults`. I have used this function earlier but always to set default existing default argument values. I did not notice the clear example that [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) provides:

```
>>> # sub-command functions
>>> def foo(args):
...     print(args.x * args.y)
...
>>> def bar(args):
...     print('((%s))' % args.z)
...
>>> # create the top-level parser
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
>>>
>>> # create the parser for the "foo" command
>>> parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
>>> parser_foo.add_argument('-x', type=int, default=1)
>>> parser_foo.add_argument('y', type=float)
>>> parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)
>>>
>>> # create the parser for the "bar" command
>>> parser_bar = subparsers.add_parser('bar')
>>> parser_bar.add_argument('z')
>>> parser_bar.set_defaults(func=bar)
>>>
>>> # parse the args and call whatever function was selected
>>> args = parser.parse_args('foo 1 -x 2'.split())
>>> args.func(args)
2.0
>>>
>>> # parse the args and call whatever function was selected
>>> args = parser.parse_args('bar XYZYX'.split())
>>> args.func(args)
((XYZYX))
```

As you can see the line `parser_bar.set_defaults(func=bar)` sets a new variable to `parser_bar` arguments. In this case `bar` is a function that is eventually used as the sub-command executor in line `args.func(args)`.

I hope this helps someone in the future.